# Unity3D player camera error cs0119

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a basic script in C# to make my camera follow my player while they walk around. I'm following the 3rd camera tutorial listed [here](http://www.saintannsny.org/depart/computer/classes/gameprog/miker_unity_scripting_tutorial.html). The code is all in javascript, and while its easy to translate i'm afraid something might be missing for that reason. I'm receiving the following error:

> PlayerCamera.cs(21,65): error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type',
>   where a`variable', `value' or`method group' was expected

which refers to this line of code:

```
newPosition += Quaternion.Euler(0, yAngle, 0) * Vector3(0.0f, distanceAbove, -distanceAway);
```

I've already tried newing the Vector3 in line and using a separate variable to store said Vector3 before multiplying, and I've kind of run out of ideas as I'm pretty new to programming in Unity. Any and all help is appreciated!

Full code for reference:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform player;
    public float smoothTime = 0.3f;
    public float distanceAbove = 3.0f;
    public float distanceAway = 5.0f;
    private float yVelocity = 0.0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        float yAngle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y,
                                             player.eulerAngles.y,
                                             ref yVelocity,
                                             smoothTime);

        Vector3 newPosition = player.position;

        newPosition += Quaternion.Euler(0, yAngle, 0) * Vector3(0.0f, distanceAbove, -distanceAway);

        gameObject.transform.position = newPosition;
        gameObject.transform.LookAt(player);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# structs (in your case `Vector3`) have to initialized with the `new` keyword.

```
newPosition += Quaternion.Euler(0, yAngle, 0) * new Vector3(0.0f, distanceAbove, -distanceAway);
```

Comment: thank you, i actually looked more in depth at what was happening in my debug log. when i added the new, the 1 error CS0119 would disappear but 7 different errors would appear. I thought those 7 errors were from that change, but they were for whatever reason in an unrelated script and only showed themselves after i fixed the camera script....silly me. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand but if you want a camera to follow your controller, why not just make it a child-object and put it in the position you want?